# React - Error while rendering child component with prop passed from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-props, react-children

I have a problem while creating my react app. I'm fetching data from CoinGecko API to build a crypto tracking app, but when I pass the `data` prop from the parent `App.js` to the child `Info.js`. When I try to render the page it gives me `Info.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'large')` . I really don't understand why it happens.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState("bitcoin");

  const getData = () => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coin}?localization=en`,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setData(response.data);
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(coin);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderContainer />
      <Search getData={getData} coin={coin} setCoin={setCoin} />
      <Info mcap={mcap} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Info.js**

```
function Info({ image, mcap, data }) {
 return (
    <div className="info-container">
      <div className="left-column">
        <div className="top-row">
          <div className="coin-icon-container">
            <img
              className="coin-icon"
              src={data.image.large}
              alt="coin logo"
              width="40px"
              height="40px"
            ></img>
          </div>
          <div className="coin-name-container">
            <p className="coin-name">{data.name}</p>
            <p className="coin-abbr">{data.symbol}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="coin-MCAP-details">
            <p className="coin-position">#{data.market_cap_rank}</p>
            <p className="coin-MCAP">{data.market_data.market_cap.usd}</p>
          </div>
```

The same error happens with the market cap in the second to last line of code. `data.name` and `data.symbol` render correctly.

The `response.json` file is very long, so i'll just put the important parts:

**Response.json**

```
{
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "symbol": "btc",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "asset_platform_id": null,
     .......
    "image":{
    "thumb": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "small": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/small/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "large": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579"
    }
    .........
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetData` is by default an empty object, and because Axios request is called in `useEffect`. On the first render `Info` component receives empty `data` object.

To way to solve it.

- Add Loading state.
- Or Add Optional chaining (data?.image?.large)

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding optional chaining worked!